# Git on Window prevent multiple branch with different case

Tags: git, azure-devops, case-sensitive

A few time I have had an issue when pushing branches to VSTS I will end up with multiple versions of the same branch but different case.

Just wondering if there are a way to config my git locally to prevent this from happening?

Comment: Is your local OS Windows? If yes are you sure you can create both branches locally?

Answer (score 0):

The setting you want is actually on the server instead of locally. There is an [option in Azure DevOps](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/repos/git/repository-settings?view=azure-devops&tabs=browser#cross-platform-compatibility-settings) that will prevent anyone from pushing branch names that differ from existing branch names by case only. (If you're still using VSTS I assume the setting exists there too.)

[image]

If you test locally on a Windows OS you should find that you already cannot create two branches that differ by case only. But you can create a branch called *testing*, push it out, delete the local branch and create a new branch called *Testing*, and push it out. To prevent that you should enable the option on the server.